# As an AngularJS developer, should I focus in learning jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have been slinging AngularJS for a while and have noticed that every once in a while I find myself thinking the following: I could make this EVEN MORE dynamic by using jQuery. My thing is, many times I have heard that AngularJS is a tad bit at odds with the jQuery programming paradigm. AngularJS best practices differ from those of jQuery (one of my favorite questions on it is here: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)).

Essentially, the question that I want to ask to all you AngularJS developers is:

As a person with limited time resources, do you feel that learning jQuery substantially increased the quality of your web applications in such a manner as making it justifiable to make a substantial time investment?

Comment: I'm not nor have I ever been a "jQuery guy,"  however from what I've seen in the AngularJS community the general consensus is if you know jQuery, try to forget it while you learn Angular since there is probably an Angular way to handle the problem that will result in a cleaner more testable solution and potentially can completely leave out jQuery, easing the transition for new devs.  That said understanding all the tools under the sun would be ideal.  Really all I know about jQuery is how to use the CSS style selectors to get at elements, beyond that I haven't used it extensively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing jQuery is helpful for building directives, since they're really the place you do DOM manipulation. With a limited time budget though, it's probably easier for you to use 3rd party directives like Angular UI.

Here are some of the things angular takes over for jQuery: click events, http, two way updates, class switching, hide / show, form validation, sorting, and reformatting output (filters). So those are things you -don't- have to learn in jQuery any more. Knowing jQuery is always useful, especially when doing quick debugging, but one of the reasons I love Angular is because I don't have to write tons of DOM manipulation code in jQuery any more.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's better to be focused in learning **JavaScript** ;)

And use more ng- directives instead of reinventing the wheels with angular.element(the same as jQueryLight) event binding.